# Вместо "Добро пожаловать в open server" - Windows iss.net

Tags: openserver, localhost

**Проблема:** вместо загрузочного экрана open serverA получаю следующее:

[image: iss.net]

Созданные папки в domains также не открываются. 
Помоги это исправить, плз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас конфликт между двумя web серверами.

Решить проблему можно отключив одно, когда используется другое. Или можно перенастроить Apache из OpenServer или IIS на другой порт.

Ещё вариант. Поместить один из web серверов на виртуальную машину.

Comment: Устанавливал только OpenServer, поэтому откуда взялся второй не могу понять. Как найти/отключить конфликтующий сервер или перенастроить оба?

Comment: Значит он был кем-то установлен ранее. Отключить IIS можно в панели управления. OpenServer в трее. По настройке Apache и IIS можно без труда нагуглить статей.

Comment: Просто хоть это и обширная тема, но она поднималась уже не раз. Да и документация у вендоров есть.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение проблемы:**

1) Зашел в "панель управления"

2) Выбрал "программы"

3) Открыл "Включение и выключение компонентов"

4) Отключил: EI, Службы и ядро IIS

5) Переустановил Open Server, так как была ошибка с "Apache 2.4 server.conf"

**Итог:** Все заработало, как было нужно.

Наглядную инструкцию прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Панель управления
2. Сис. и безопасность
3. Администрирование
4. Службы IIS *(не службы IIS 6.0)*
5. Открываете первый пункт , далее открывайте Сайты
   и выбирайте самое первое
6. Нажмите на него правой кнопкой мыши и выберите остановить.
   Все **должно работать.**
   **На FTP сервера не повлияет!**